# Android Layout - when to use app: vs android:?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I've been writing some Android apps but I don't really understand when to use `app:` and when to use `android:`. When styles are not being applied the way they're supposed to, I use trial and error and sometimes find that using `app:` instead of `android:` solves the issue but I don't understand why. It'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: when you are using custom attributes ... it also apply to atributtes from support libraries ... also app is not precise as it is simply namespace shortcut and what it means depends on definition (fx: if you put `xmlns:and="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` you would be able to use `and:` instead `android:`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are talking about custom namespace.In android we can create custom views in additional to already available views.
As per in Google developer docs..
To add a built-in View to your user interface, you specify it in an XML element and control its appearance and behavior with element attributes. Well-written custom views can also be added and styled via XML. To enable this behavior in your custom view, you must:

Define custom attributes for your view in a  resource element
Specify values for the attributes in your XML layout
Retrieve attribute values at runtime
Apply the retrieved attribute values to your view

Once you define the custom attributes, you can use them in layout XML files just like built-in attributes. The only difference is that your custom attributes belong to a different namespace. Instead of belonging to the http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android namespace, they belong to http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[your package name]

So for if you use default views you can use android namespace and if you want to set and use attributes for custom view you can define your own name.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the app namespace to have app compatibility with older API versions.

For example 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/customborder" has the same effects with 
android:background="@drawable/customborder"
The difference is that the first will work correctly with older API's and the second will not display what you would like.

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the beginning of the your layout xml files (in which you used `app:`) you will (probably) find lines like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOME_LAYOUT xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

in this case `app:` namespace will be used for custom attributes, specified by you inside `attrs.xml` file or by someone else in one of used libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Sometime the property with android only available in new Android version like
[image]

In this case, you should use `app:...` to make it work with older version.

Comment: this is the best answer so far!

Answer (score 1):

moreover you will find two variants

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/[packagename]"
```

the difference between xmlns lines is res-auto take care of resolving our package as sometime we will add .debug or .test in our package and we already provided the packageid of the app Ex:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.test.io.debug"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.test.io.test"
```