# In ConstraintLayout, we use 'app' while in RelativeLayout, we use 'android'. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

While using Android Studio, I came across constraint layout. I used the below mentioned link to understand all about it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#RelativePositioning

but I still have a small question. In RelativeLayout, we use `android:layout_alignParentBottom`, `android:layout_alignParentTop`, etc. They all start with `android`. But in ConstraintLayout, we have to use `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf`, etc.

Can you explain me the difference between using `app` and `android` prefix and their importance?

Comment: because constraint layout is part of the support library, so it's supported resource values have to be added separately.

Comment: See below links. I hope it helps . [Android Layout - when to use app: vs android:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045648/android-layout-when-to-use-app-vs-android) [What is the 'app' Android XML namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692233/what-is-the-app-android-xml-namespace) [Difference between android: and app: prefix in Android XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732512/difference-between-android-and-app-prefix-in-android-xml)

Answer (score 0):

`android` is usually used for attribute coming from Android SDK itself.

`app` is often used if you are using the support library.

ConstraintLayout is new layout available in the support library. hence the "app"