# Issues on onCreateOptionsMenu for android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int) on a null object reference

Tags: android

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.material.components, PID: 11563
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.material.components.activity.dashboard.Dashboard.onCreateOptionsMenu(Dashboard.java:251)
```

The problems at this line:-

```
ui_hot = menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);
```

What's happen? I tried to `findViewById` in menu but android could not ever find object reference. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Full codes:

***Dashboard.java:***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu);
    final View menu_hotlist = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification).getActionView();
    ui_hot = menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot); //Problem location
    updateHotCount(hot_number);
    new MyMenuItemStuffListener(menu_hotlist, "Show hot message") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

***menu_dashboard.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_notifitcation_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
        android:title="Notifications"
        />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/lessons_discuss_with_teacher"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Ask Teacher List"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

***action_bar_notification_icon.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hotlist_bell"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notifications"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="bell"
        />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/hotlist_hot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="17sp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@null"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438890/menuitemcompat-getactionview-always-returns-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438890/menuitemcompat-getactionview-always-returns-null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**`NullPointerException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the null value.

Try with

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu);   
    MenuItem menuITEM = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
    View view         = menuITEM.getActionView();
    ui_hot            = view.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);
```

**FYI**

You should call **`app:actionLayout`**

Comment: @Nere where you call `action_bar_notification_icon` layout?

Comment: `android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_notifitcation_icon"`

Comment: I called it in `menu_dashboard.xml`

Comment: @Nere call `app:actionLayout`

Comment: So..what's the difference if I use `android:actionLayout`?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045648/android-layout-when-to-use-app-vs-android

Comment: Thanks! You really help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportMenuInflater

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_actionbar, menu);
    final View menu_hotlist = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_hotlist).getActionView();
    ui_hot = (TextView) menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);
    updateHotCount(hot_number);
    new MyMenuItemStuffListener(menu_hotlist, "Show hot message") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code
        }
    };
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: could not found `getSupportMenuInflater()`?